My wife doesn't like visiting my family often, is she sinning this makes my mother angry
In my family we have lots of gathering and social events with cousins and everyone, my wife says she likes to keep a good distant relationship and meet from time to time not every day but my mother wants her to meet and mingle in the family with family members, my wife is also very shy and she pleases me everyway possible but she just doesnt like going and meeting my mother often, this makes my mother really upset and sad and she went through alot so what do i do?
My mother often fights with me regarding my wife and i get stuck in between, my wife is loved by everyone in my family and they often invite her to their house to meet their kids and their family but my wife likes to be indoors ( she always prefers being at home )
Can I force her?
Can she refuse always? is she on the right? am i sinning?

Welcome to Islam SE. Please read https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and make sure that your question only contains one, specific, pin-pointed query instead of multiple questions. You can edit the question by clicking the edit button below your post.

Islamically she is not sinning. She is not responsible for your mother. Even if she never see your mother or want to see your mother she is not sinning.
You are responsible for your mom. You have to take care of your mother. She can't stop you from seeing and spending time with your mom. So give your mom her rights and give your wife her rights.
As far as forcing, you can't do that. She is not responsible for your mom, she is responsible to take care of the household when u r absent and take care of the kids. That's it. Just like u are not responsible for her parents.
Now as a wife or husband even if you don't like spending time with each other family, then you should try your best to do it as it would make your spouse happy.
Talk to you wife, maybe don't ask her all the time, give her extra love. And INSHALLAH she will want to make you happy so she will visit. Make a alot dua.

In Islam it is prescribed for women to remain at home and to not go out without a need.

وقرن في بيوتكن ولا تبرجن تبرج الجاهلية الأولى
And abide in your houses and do not display yourselves as [was] the display of the former times of ignorance.
— Quran 33:33


المرأة عورة، وإنها إذا خرجت استشرفها الشيطان، وإنها لا تكون إلى وجه الله أقرب منها في قعر بيتها
Woman is ‘awrah (that which must be concealed), and when she goes out the Shaytaan’s hopes are raised. She is never closer to Allah than in the inner part of her house.
— Sahih Ibn Khuzaimah and Saheeh Ibn Hibban

Also Islam prescribes veiling and forbids unnecessary mingling with non-mahrams, even if they be the family of the husband:

‏ إياكم والدخول على النساء ‏.‏ فقال رجل من الأنصار يا رسول الله أفرأيت الحمو‏.‏ قال الحمو الموت
Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Beware of entering upon the ladies." A man from the Ansar said, "Allah's Apostle! What about Al-Hamu the in-laws of the wife (the brothers of her husband or his nephews etc.)?" The Prophet (ﷺ) replied: The in-laws of the wife are death itself.
— Bukhari

You can not force your wife to do something which is against the teachings of Islam and she is not obliged to obey you in such matters. Rather you should attempt to correct the expectations of your mother.

Wfe not to go and visit your mum is depend on you
If you create a schedule of yourself to visit you mother then it will get on blood
Sometime it happens that the talk each other back this enrolled to hate each others in this to have to train you family not talking bad to anyone but keep paying for them and say good for them this will increase kindness and unity
Make sure to keep limit upon all parties
To yourself you mother is the first and to your wife his mother is still first to her so respect is the key to success to all parties and insha'Allah
Allah knows the best
